# React Socket, on file change error "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"

Tags: json, reactjs, socket.io

I am piping data through a socket on changes to a json file. So far, I have a script being ran on an interval to create the JSON file. I have an express server to watch for changes to the file, if so, then emit the data. I receive the data and setState to it. When the file changes, I get the error and I don't know why.

Server code

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log("User connected " + socket.id);
    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (err, res) => {
        // console.log('on connection ' + JSON.stringify(res));
        io.emit('send data', res);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log("user disconnected " + socket.id);
    });
});

fs.watch(filePath, (eventName, filename) => {
    if (filename) {
        console.log('Data updated');
        io.emit('send data', fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8'));
    }
});
```

React code:

```
// import packages
import React, { Component } from "react";
import io from 'socket.io-client';

// import Homepage from './components/homepage/Homepage.js'

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: null
        };
        this.socket = io('http://localhost:5000');

        // Binders
        this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.socket.on('send data', this.updateState);
    }

    updateState(result) {
        this.setState({
            data: JSON.parse(result)
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                {!this.state.data ? "" : JSON.stringify(this.state.data.name)}
            </p>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Is the returned JSON validated ? Copy the response from network and validate in some online tool.

Comment: Looks like your returned response is not in valid JSON format and thats why JSON.parse is creating issue for you.

Comment: JSON is not validated because it's sent through as a string. I have made sure my python script writes the files accurately. It's just on a change, the file change causes the error. @rach8garg

Comment: @HemadriDasari is it possible that the JSON file is too big to load at once and fires multiple events that it causes this error? If so, how do I go about this issue??

Answer (score 0):

fs.readFile was reading the JSON file too quickly, I added a 5 second delay as such

```
var end = Date.now() + 5000;
while (Date.now() < end);
```